# How to validate mariadb/mysqld configuration options while it is running

Tags: mysql, configuration

Is there a way to validate mysql.cnf files while mysqld is running?
If I run mysqld --validate-config, it just hangs, because there is already one running.
mysqld is scheduled to restart at 3am every morning and I want to be able to tweak the settings without worrying that a typo will kill mysql until I wake up and check the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just researching the same problem.

I don't think mariadb's mysqld supports --validate-config, at least mysqld --verbose --help does not mention it.

Maybe only Oracle's mysqld supports it?

Answer (score 0):

For version 8, this is from the manual, see this URL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-validation.html